# References to sections in apa6 not working

Tags: sectioning, citing, apa-style, apa6

How do I refer to a section using

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
```

What I tried:

- `\ref{sec:section_name}`: latex completely ignored this.
- `\ref{section_name}`: this was ignored as well.
- `nameref{sec:related_work}`: worked if I also added `\usepackage{hyperref}`; however, it seems that this package does not work together with the `apa` package, for it created many more errors with my citing (`\cite{}`).

I don't know what else to try. I wouldn't have thought that such a basic thing was impossible in latex. I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

### A minimal Version of my document:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\title{.......}

\abstract{yada yada}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
intro intro intro....

\section{section two}
\label{sec:section_two}
Here I would like to refer to section 1 (the introduction), somehow
```

Comment: `ignored` is not really useful. Do you have any `\label` statements in your document? Please show us a minimal version of your document that generates this issue!

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer; yes, I have labels in my document. I edited the question and added some of the document. Thanks!

Comment: Your document does not work because it's incomplete. But a look into the documentation reveals: `apa6` does not support numbered sections, so a label is useless then.

Comment: The `\nameref` version works because the relevant information is written to `.aux` file, so `nameref` can make use of it, by establishing a separate counting scheme

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - yes, there are no section numbers; therefore I would expect a reference to a section to consist of its name. That's exactly what `\nameref` did, and I would have used it if it hadn't caused so many other errors.

Comment: Perhaps you should really post the version that did not work (and this time,  no fragments, please!)

Answer (score 4):

Found `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` in `apa6.cls`, which will produce nothing with `\ref` command.

For more errors with `\cite`, use option `natbib`

[image: From APA6 Documentation]

Comment: This might be a solution, but it seems to be in conflict with APA specifications.